# Is it possible to expand this code like have more that 2 options?

Tags: node.js, angular, navbar, title

here is my code to get the titles of each:

```
export class WrapperComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  DASHBOARD = 'Dashboard'
  DASHBOARD_URL = 'dashboard'
  PERSONAL_INFORMATION = 'Personal Information'
  PERSONAL_INFORMATION_URL = 'personal-information'
  EMPLOYEE_HISTORY = 'Employee History'
  EMPLOYEE_HISTORY_URL = 'employee-history'
  navBarTitle = this.DASHBOARD
  subs: Subscription[] = [];
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subToRouterEvents();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (0 === this.subs.length) {
      return;
    }
    this.subs.forEach((sub) => sub.unsubscribe());
  }

  subToRouterEvents() {
    const routeEventSub = this.router.events.subscribe(this.routerEventHandler);
    this.subs.push(routeEventSub);
  }

  routerEventHandler = (event: Event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      const routeText = this.router.url.split('/');
      this.evalRouteUrl(routeText[3]);
    }
  };
  evalRouteUrl(url: string) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof url) return;
    this.navBarTitle = url === this.DASHBOARD_URL ? this.DASHBOARD : this.PERSONAL_INFORMATION
  }
}
```

and here's my code for html:

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb bg-transparent mb-0 pb-0 pt-1 px-0 me-sm-6 me-5">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item text-sm" *ngIf="navBarTitle === 'Personal Information'">
          <a class="opacity-5 text-white">My Account</a>
        </li>
        <li
          class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-white active"
          aria-current="page" *ngIf="navBarTitle === 'Personal Information'"
        >
          My Profile
        </li>
        <li
          class="breadcrumb-item text-sm text-white active"
          aria-current="page"
        >
          {{ navBarTitle }}
        </li>
      </ol>
      <h6 class="font-weight-bolder text-white mb-0 text-uppercase">
        {{ navBarTitle }}
      </h6>
    </nav>
```

Can anyone help me get the titles of navbars... I have this code but it only take 2 options. It would be a great help for me.

Is it possible to expand this code like have more that 2 options?

```
 evalRouteUrl(url: string) {
    if ('undefined' === typeof url) return;
    this.navBarTitle = url === this.DASHBOARD_URL ? this.DASHBOARD : this.PERSONAL_INFORMATION
  }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow has a super code editor. Please post code, not images. So we can work with it and can help you better.

Comment: There I change them.. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please, not use images to show code else write the code, select all and use Ctrl+K to format it (It's hard read a question with images)

You should "parametrize your app". That's use an array of objects

If you have an array like

```
paths=[{path:'dashboard', title:'Dashboard'},
       {path:'personal-information', title:'Personal Information'},
       ...
      ]
```

You can find in the array by path and return the title

```
evalRouter(url:string)
{
   const path=this.paths.find(x=>x.path==url)
   this.navBarTitle=path?path.title:''
}
```

BTW: you can use the **new** property (from Angular 15 -in bellow versions you use the "data" property-) title in your [Routes](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#properties), e.g.

```
const routes=[{
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  title:'Dashboard'
}, {
  path: 'personal-information',
  component: PersonalInfoComponent,
  title:'Dashboard'
}
...
]
```

Comment: This works but I can only fetch dashboard... I'm using multiple routing modules and this code can only find parent routes. Both my personal-information and employee-history are child of my-account route. If I use only the parent's path, it works only on personal-information.